# Rails app on Heroku status 500 internal server error (We're sorry but something went wrong)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, internal-server-error

Hello so I have an app that works great locally but as soon as I pushed it to Heroku I'm having issues.

HEROKU LINK: https://sleepy-garden-73993.herokuapp.com
GITHUB REPO: https://github.com/kbachand/ginger_ails

ERROR IN CONSOLE WHEN INSPECT THE PAGE:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

HOW TO DUPLICATE ISSUE:
-Click "check your address", ENTER address: 202 tryon st; ZIP code: 28207 (this is in our service area)
-Click "select your ailment" and select one (any will work)
-Click "purchase remedy kit", and it will prompt you to login or sign up. You can sign up if you'd like but my login is keithbtest@gmail.com and password: surfsup714
-Once you login click "purchase remedy kit" and it SHOULD render a view that shows you all the items in the cart and allows you to empty or purchase via stripe. But instead you get the error.

HEROKU LOG:

```
2016-11-02T18:15:02.693028+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mCart Load (1.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]  
2016-11-02T18:15:02.696486+00:00 app[web.1]:   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer  
2016-11-02T18:15:02.695276+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35mUser Load (1.8ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (1) LIMIT 1  
2016-11-02T18:15:02.695572+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)  
2016-11-02T18:15:02.696484+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2016-11-02T18:15:02.696487+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                 ^
2016-11-02T18:15:02.696486+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (1) LIMIT 1  
2016-11-02T18:15:02.696488+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (1) LIMIT 1):  
2016-11-02T18:15:02.696488+00:00 app[web.1]:     app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:35:in `show'  
2016-11-02T18:15:02.696489+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2016-11-02T18:15:02.696489+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2016-11-02T18:18:42.858131+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sleepy-garden-73993.herokuapp.com request_id=5c66a6cc-7de8-43b6-92c3-51b63a3d3ab7 fwd="104.139.26.81" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=6966
```

Comment: You just need `User.find(params[:id])` on line 35 of carts_controller.rb

Comment: I had that and it didn't work. There was a comment that must of been deleted that said to add this: @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])   which works. As a junior level developer I'd like to know why it has to be like that to work vs the way you just typed out.

Comment: `User.find_by_xyz(xyz: 1)` will look for whatever attribute comes after `find_by_`. In this case `xyz`. If you just search by `find()`, it will search by the primary key, which in your case is probably `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important bits on the log are:

"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer "

Below it reads the error is on `app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:35`
https://github.com/kbachand/ginger_ails/blob/master/app/controllers/carts_controller.rb#L35

On that line you have:

```
@user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

So it looks like `params[:id]` is an integer, but the `id` column is a boolean.

When looking at your schema.rb to check your column types, I realized you have the `devise` gem installed, so you should use devise's helpers to authenticate the user instead of doing it manually:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: thank you for that! I'll definitely start using the devise helpers instead which will make my life easier anyways!

Comment: @KeithBachand glad to help! Would you mind accepting the answer?